# Keyboard shortcut keys with no scancode?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 2000, model #1477, running on Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit with a strange issue. It has a row of shortcut keys along the top (one of the reasons I chose it), but only half of them work.

I thought the nonfunctional keys weren't assigned and just needed to be mapped, but going through the keys using `showkey --scancodes` doesn't provide any response. Does this mean the keys aren't sending any signal at all to the system? That seems extremely weird to me. There is [a driver for the keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-ca/d/wireless-keyboard-2000), but I wanted to find out if there was a native way to get these keys working before I started trying to wrestle a Microsoft driver into cooperating.

Here are the keys by label and the scancodes for those that give them:

*(home icon):* 0xe0 0x32, 0xe0 0xb2
*(envelope):* 0xe0 0x6c, 0xe0 0x6c 0xe0 0xec
*(1):

(2):

(3):

(4):

(5):

(star):* 0xe0 0x66, 0xe0 0x66 0xe0 0xe6
*(- magnifying glass):

(+ magnifying glass):

(play/pause):* 0xe0 0x22, 0xe0 0xa2
*(«):* 0xe0 0x10, 0xe0 0x90
*(»):* 0xe0 0x19, 0xe0 0x99
*(speaker down):* 0xe0 0x2e, 0xe0 0xae
*(speaker up):* 0xe0 0x30, 0xe0 0xb0